Draft question?
I was writing a new question based on some insight that struck me in the middle some conversation and realized that i just don't have the time at the moment to research all the factors. I had already written out some of the questions and would prefer to save(privately) and then come back and edit it here.
I don't know whether other stackexchange sites have it but i think it is a good feature to have in sites like these where the focus is research level sharing. Any opinions/suggestions?

For answers, drafts are already saved every 45 seconds, automatically. You can navigate away and come back, and your draft will still be there.
That's not the case for questions, because there's no URL attached to an un-posted question. I would suggest you simply save it in a text file on your computer.
In general, Meta Stack Overflow is the place to go to request features that apply to all of StackExchange... CogSci meta is mostly just for questions related specifically to CogSci.SE.
You can try posting your feature request on Meta Stack Overflow. Though, from observational experience (reading a lot of meta posts), I think this idea might get shot down as too much bloat--SE likes to keep the interface simple. But feel free to try.

Thanks.. i'll accept and close.. i don't have the time to justify it to all of StackExchange, besides this reasoning might be useful only to handful of StackExchange sites(Cogsci, mathoverflow etc..)
